# Loop through workbook and sheets in each workbook vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through all Workbooks in a folder and then loop through all worksheets of each workbook. I have the code below but currently the problem is with the line `For Each ws in StrFile.Sheets`:

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir("C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\bob\VBAProject\Raw\")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        Debug.Print StrFile
        For Each ws In StrFile.Sheets
            Debug.Print ws.Name
        Next ws
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to loop through all `Workbook.Sheets` you need to `Set wb` to the current `StrFile`, and then loop through `wb.Sheets`.

Using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` will minimize all screen flickering and Excel alerts.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim StrFile As Variant
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    fPath = "C:\Users\A9900899\Desktop\bob\VBAProject\Raw\"
    StrFile = Dir(fPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    While StrFile <> ""
        Debug.Print StrFile
        If StrFile Like "*xls*" Then ' check that current file is Excel type
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath & StrFile)
            For Each ws In wb.Sheets
                Debug.Print ws.Name
            Next ws
            wb.Close False ' close workbook and don't save changes
        End If
        StrFile = Dir
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Is it necessary to Open the workbook in order to loop through the sheets? Can I loop through the sheets to do something without opening the workbook? Thanks

Comment: Depends what kind of operations you want to do ? Also, you didn't mention that in your post.